# Pandas groupby and add total for numeric column and for time column ,want to add average

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

```
 A      B     C    Time       D
1     sandy    12   02:30:24   California
2     sandy    22   01:24:06   California
3     sunny    8    05:03:52   Rhode Island
4     sunny    32   07:03:25    Rhode Island

Required output
 A      B      C   Time              D
1     sandy    12   02:30:24         California
2              22   01:24:06         California
sandy Total    34   01:57:15
3     sunny    8    05:03:52         Rhode Island
4              32   07:03:25        Rhode Island
sunny Total    40   06:03:38
      Total    74   04:00:27
```

want to add a total of the numeric columns at the end of each group and average time (i have two time column in actual)of time column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the Total lines by [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) and  [`.assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), the Grand Total line by [`pd.Series()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html). Then, append to the original `df` by [`.append()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html), followed by [`sort_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) to sort back together the same column `B` ('sandy', 'sunny'):

```
df_total = (df.assign(Time=pd.to_timedelta(df['Time']))
              .groupby('B')[['C', 'Time']]
              .agg({'C': 'sum', 'Time': lambda x: str(x.mean().round('1s')).split()[-1]})
              .assign(A='Total: ', D='')
           )

df_grand_total = pd.Series({'A': '', 
                            'C': df['C'].sum(),
                            'Time': str(pd.to_timedelta(df['Time']).mean().round('1s')).split()[-1],
                            'D': ''},
                            name='~Grand Total:')

df_final = (df.set_index('B')
              .append(df_total)
              .append(df_grand_total)              
              .sort_index()
              .reset_index()
           )
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_total)

        C      Time        A D
B                             
sandy  34  01:57:15  Total:   
sunny  40  06:03:38  Total:   


print(df_grand_total)

A               
C             74
Time    04:00:27
D               
Name: ~Grand Total:, dtype: object


print(df_final)

               B        A   C      Time             D
0          sandy        1  12  02:30:24    California
1          sandy        2  22  01:24:06    California
2          sandy  Total:   34  01:57:15              
3          sunny        3   8  05:03:52  Rhode Island
4          sunny        4  32  07:03:25  Rhode Island
5          sunny  Total:   40  06:03:38              
6  ~Grand Total:           74  04:00:27
```

Comment: and also how to add column wise grand total and total average at the end.

Comment: @SanjuM  See my edit on the enhancement to support grand total.

Comment: @SanjuM  Fine-tuned the codes a bit.  You can refer to the latest edit.